# Non-Space delimited text file to 2D vector

Tags: c++

I've got a file that can be of any size and is a series of `char` values without any spaces between (except a blank space is treated as a blank cell of a grid).

```
xxxxxxx
xx   xx
xxyyyxx
```

After some great help I've gone with the method to use a `vector<vector<char> >` however I cannot seem to populate it.

```
void readCourse(istream& fin) {

    // using 3 and 7 to match example shown above
    vector<vector<char> > data(3, vector<char>(7));

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            fin.get(data[i][j]); // I believe the problem exists here
        }                        // Does the .get() method work here?
    }                            // Or does it need to be .push_back()?

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            cout << data[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Is my method for populating my 2D vector valid? If not, can you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: what about a really big file ? could you store it completely into the memory ?

Comment: You seem to forget that the file also contains newlines.

Comment: Why not use `std::vector<std::stirng>` and `std::getline`?

Comment: @NathanOliver If the width is fixed, then a vector of vectors is fine. Could still use `std::getline` to read each line from the file though, and use that to populate each row.

Comment: @NathanOliver If you have a 2D vector containing strings, can you output a specific position of the string? Meaning, if my `vector[0]` was `Hello!`, using `getline` could I do `cout << vector[0][1]` and output `e`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It don't think you gain anything from that and it makes it easier/shorter to populate the vector.

Comment: @pasta_sauce Yes.  It performs exactly the same but is easier to use.`vector[index]` gives you a `string&` so `vector[index][index]` gives you the character at `index` of the string at `index`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude How does the `\r\n` impact my vector?

Comment: @NathanOliver I've posted a potential fix. However, I cant test right now. Does having a vector of vectors of type `char` change the method of `push_back(line)` as `line` is a `string`?

Comment: @pasta_sauce Yes.  You would have to iterate the string and push individual character into the vector

Comment: The `fin.get()` call you make will read the newline character (or characters) as well, and you will add them to your vector.

Comment: @pasta_sauce you should not edit your own answer into your question. [This is what is allowed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing). Instead, [please make a separate answer to your own question.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @NathanOliver I've updated the potential solution. I'm not sure my iterator is correct and again I cant test.

Comment: @NathanOliver Post my answer based on your suggestion. No need to specify a `std::vector<std::vector<char> >`. Thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution I ended up using after ADT implementation**:

```
  void readCourse(std::istream& fin) {
        std::vector<std::string> level
        std::string line;
        while(std::getline(fin, line) {
            level.push_back(line);
        }            

        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (std::size_t j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                std::cout << data[i][j];
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: FYI you can test using online compilers like ideone.com. For example: http://ideone.com/7iFh4l (I made some changes to your code to make it compile).

Answer (score 0):

I'd keep it simple and efficient with a single `vector<char>`:

```
vector<char> readCourse(istream& fin) {
    vector<char> course(3*(7+2)); // 3x7 plus newlines
    fin.read(course.data(), course.size());
    course.resize(fin.gcount());
    auto end = remove(course.begin(), course.end(), '\n');
    end = remove(course.begin(), end, '\r');
    course.erase(end, course.end()); // purge all \n and \r
    return course;
}
```

That's a single input operation to get all the data, followed by removing the characters you don't need.  You can then access the result in a 2D way like this:

```
course.at(x + y*7) // assuming width 7
```

That may seem a bit inconvenient, but it is efficient and compact--the overhead is always three pointers and a single heap allocation, instead of being proportional to the number of rows.